# Cannot resolve symbol T

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a problem with ObservableCollection Class. I cant resolve this.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    #region ViewModelProperty: CustomerList
    private ObservableCollection<T> _customerList = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    public ObservableCollection<T> CustomerList
    {
      get
      {
        return _customerList;
      }

      set
      {
        _customerList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CustomerList");
      }
    }
    #endregion
```

My class with the ObservableCollection inherits ViewModelBase:

```
  public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
```

any idea, where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` is just a placeholder. You need to supply an actual type somewhere for `T`.

E.g. if you have `List<T>`, you could make a `List<int>` or `List<string>` (`T` is any other type which fits the given constraints). I.e. `T` is `int` in the first case and `string` in the second.

Comment: I have 2 different types what I add this collection see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: You still need to substitute T with a specific type. If your different types have a common base class, you can use this for T. If they don't you can use object, but in that case you might want to consider changing your design.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will become clear to you when you read up a bit on [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx)

You could do it like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> customerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>()
```

Then, you have a typed collection which will be able to store instances of the Customer class (and also instances of subclasses that inherit from Customer).
So, if you want to have a collection where you want to be able to add instances of multiple types, you could create a base-class (or interface), and inherit from that base-class or implement this interface, and create an ObservableCollection instance for ex.

Comment: I have a base-class Customer an two classes (PrivateCustomer and CorporateCustomer) there inherits from Customer. Now I would like any Subclasses object adding in only one ObservableCollection there bind to one DataGrid.

Answer (score -1):

As previously posted, T is a placeholder. You probably want something like:

```
private ObservableCollection<T> _customerList = new ObservableCollection < ClassYouWantObserved > ();
```

Comment: That snippet is plainly wrong ;). Guess you want to change the first T too.